# Grouping with Scala For-Comprehention

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I recently failed an exam and a major point was a task where I had to use a for-comprehensions, or rather ONLY for-comprehensions.

Data: `List[(day: Int, month: String, reason: String, km: int)]`

```scala
val data = List(
  (25, "February", "1", 25),
  (17, "April", "1", 63),
  (19, "March", "3", 45),
  (17, "October", "4", 12),
  (25, "December", "1", 45),
  (9, "January", "2", 56),
  (17, "April", "1", 54),
  (21, "September", "3", 16),
  (3, "May", "2", 59),
  (20, "January", "4", 46),
  (28, "June", "5", 28),
  (19, "March", "3", 34),
  (29, "August", "1", 42),
  (17, "April", "1", 77)
)

def moreThanTwoViolations(maxKm: Int, in: List[(Int, String, String, Int)]) : List[(Int, String)] = ???
```

#### Task:

Find all the days, where in which least 2 times `minKm > km` for the same or different reason.

#### Example:

if `maxKm = 30` then `List[(19, "March", "2", 45), (19, "March", "3", 34)]` are relevant, because for 2 `reason`s fulfil `_._4 > 30`, so I would return `List[(19, "March")]`.

I don't get how to solve this without using `groupBy` because that means I'd have to "remember" a day to compere my current state to a state I already looked at. And I can't keep a state with for-comprehensions.

part 2 of this would be to de-sugar part 1, so instead of for-comps, use only `map`, `flatmap` and `filter`.

Sorry if this comes across like a noob question, but without grouping this seems ridiculous and I just want to know what I missed here.

Comment: You do not need to group data, you need to filter data. I guess that should be enough to get you on the right path.

Comment: No, sorry. Sure I can `for(item <- data; if item._4 > 30) yield {...}` but I have no way of remembering if a condition has occurred before, since I need at least 2 time the same `DAY` / `REASON`. The only way to know would be to group them and then test the list length or use foldlefts accumulator. What am I missing here?

Comment: Uhm, I believe that _"two times"_ means a `_._4 * 2 > maxKm` If not, then yes, you are right, you would need to keep a state, which doesn't make much sense given the constraints of the task. I would ask your professor.

Comment: the task says: Find all days in which KM > maxKm for at least 2 (different or same) reasons. Yes, I think I'd have to keep a state and that makes no sense to me. I'm going to ask my professor about this.

Comment: Doesn't the phrase "same or different reason," and the phrase "at least 2 (different or same) reasons," basically mean that the reason is irrelevant? I mean if all the reasons could be the same and all the reasons could be different, then why pay attention to the reason at all?

Comment: The specific reason is irrelevant, it just has to be 2 violations on the same day. Which still has me keep a state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guy on reddit helped me with the answer. Turns out you don't need to keep a state to fulfil this specific requirement, just build a whack conditional. I guess I failed that exam for a reason

```scala
def moreThanTwoViolations( maxKm: Int,
                       in: List[(Int, String, String, Int)]
                     ) : List[(Int, String)] = {
  (for {
    line1 <- data
    line2 <- data
      if line1._1 == line2._1 && 
         line1._2 == line2._2 && // ._1 and ._2 are the date (needs to be different)
         line1._3 != line2._3 && // ._3 is the reason. has to be different to add up to 2
         line1._4 > maxKm && 
         line2._4 > maxKm        // both km need to be > maxKm
    } yield (line1._1, line1._2)
  ).distinct
}
```

Comment: I don't see why using `distinct` would be less of a violation of the "for comprehension only" requirement than `groupBy`. Did your professor provide the expected answer?

Comment: No answer yet. I feel like distinct is an edge case.  Without it, it get’s really tough

Comment: Yea when I saw this that was the only thing that came to mind. That aside, it seems weird to make you bend over backwards for a sub-optimal solution.

Comment: If you think that's artificial, wait till you see the for-comprehension cross join I have here